# Always get {"error":"Unsupported Media Type"} from Watson-Conversation service

Tags: watson-conversation

The following code is very straightforward.  However, when I execute it, I always get **{"error":"Unsupported Media Type"}** from Watson-Conversation service.  Please help to show me where the issue comes from.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/70b056e6-14a0-424f-9631-696272ce666e/message?version=2016-09-20",
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "{MYUSERNAME}:{MYPASSWORD}",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('message' => '{ "input": { "text": "Hola" }, "alternate_intents": false }'),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($err)
{
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
}
else
{
    echo $response;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

I have sorted it out already by adding following option into the call:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json')
```